# Is there a way to change where "/" points to in html?

Tags: html, ajax, url, request

Sometimes I like to play around with source codes of other websites, such as `google.com`. I simply copy-and-paste the code I get from typing `view-source:google.com` in my web browser and put it in an html file. However, if I have an image pointing to `/favicon.ico` instead of `http://google.com/favicon.ico`, it won't load since it looks for `favicon.ico` on my computer instead of at `google.com`. The same applies for all sorts of other html elements and AJAX requests. So, is there some magical way to change where "/" points to?

Comment: This has existed since ever [https://html.com/attributes/base-href/](https://html.com/attributes/base-href/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since changing where "/" points to in `XMLHTTPRequest` and `fetch` would violate CORS, this is not possible with AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding a base to your `head` tag:

```html
<base href="https://example.com" target="_blank"/>
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)

Comment: Works in html just fine, but doesn't apply to `fetch` or `XMLHTTPRequest`.